# Accessing local Apache website from remote machine in same network

Tags: apache, virtualhost

This is my story.

I installed Apache in windows 7 and configured Virtual host. Below is my directory tree.

```
D:\
 Apache/
 PHP/
 MySQL/
 projects/
```

and virtual host configuration.

```
<VirtualHost stuff.dev>
    DocumentRoot "D:/projects/stuff"
    ServerName stuff.dev
    ServerAlias stuff.dev
    <Directory "D:/projects/stuff">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I also add host name in hosts file. I could accessed stuff.dev in local machine but I can't access from remote machine although I add host name in remote's hosts files.

When I access website from remote machine, It's always access to default host (htdocs/index.html).

How can I access local website from remote machine?

Comment: please format the content of your configuration as code and insert line breaks

Comment: I'm sorry about that. Do you have any suggest? Must I change anything in httpd.conf file?

Answer (score 0):

If you can access via `localhost` and not from your other computer, the issue is your Windows Firewall.... try to disable it or configure it to handle `port 80`

If Windows Firewall is disabled and still not working make sure you don't have any application (like Skype) that is conflicted with Apache `port 80`

Comment: I disabled Apache's firewall, I also change Skype port. I can access to Apache from remote PC but it's not correctly. It goes to default document root (D:/Apache/htdocs/index.html) instead of goes to (D:/projects/stuff/index.php).

Comment: if you `ping stuff.dev` from your remote, what do you get? Also I am not sure when you said Apache's Firewall, what do you meant by that?? I asked your for Windows Firewall

Comment: I'm sorry, I disabled Windows Firewall. When i ping `stuff.dev`, I received Apache's IP address. I also used `nslookup` to resovle `stuff.dev` to IP address and I received `127.0.53.53`

Comment: I am not sure how you setup your network but that is an unusual IP. is that the IP address that you use in your hosts file? Normally you get an IP like 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255 or 172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255 or 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255. Depends on your network configuration. Check your IP on you server `ifconfig` and make sure to use that IP

Comment: My Apache IP address is `172.17.33.240`. I `ping stuff.dev` from remote PC and I received `172.17.33.240`.